# Loading a url from WebView without showing it

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to load a url from a `WebView` without having it attached to any layout (not visible)?

Comment: Yes. Just don't add it to your view. Create the `WebView` dynamically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use your application context to instantiate your WebView:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
webView.loadUrl("your-url");
```

Surprisingly this works... which means that a webview can actually be created with the application context and does not need a UI context which for me is a bit weird.

Comment: It is absolutely normal. You can render off-screen and then display the result as you want. E.g. a ebook reader can render the pages of the book off-screen, and then when displaying, apply a visual effect for page turning, which would be quite hard to implement in CSS.

Comment: Try to instantiate any other View with an ApplicationContext, most have unexpected side effects.

Comment: If I do it like this, I get the error: "validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)"

Comment: This solution works... (or at least worked) try loading a simple web page with just a label and see..